# Use Multiple Conditions in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

We use this code find tags containing the text "Fiscal"

```
soup.find(class_="label",text=re.compile("Fiscal"))
```

How do I put multiple conditions in here.

Lets say tags containing "Fiscal" and "year" both.

Or tags containing "Fiscal" and NOT "year"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you see that the criteria vary and they might get more complex then you could use a function as a filter e.g.:

> Lets say tags containing "Fiscal" and "year" both.

```
t = soup.find(class_="label", text=lambda s: "Fiscal" in s and "year" in s)
```

> Or tags containing "Fiscal" and NOT "year"

```
t = soup.find(class_="label", text=lambda s: "Fiscal" in s and "year" not in s)
```

You could also use a regex here but it might be less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass text as a list (this site is example from my prev answer :) )

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('http://www.snapdeal.com/products/computers-laptops?sort=plrty&')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)

elements = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'lfloat'}, text=re.compile(r'(14|4)')) # | means 'or'

print elements
```

prints `[<div class="lfloat">(14)</div>, <div class="lfloat">(4)</div>, <div class="lfloat">(45)</div>]`

So you can use: `soup.find_all(class_="label",text=re.compile(r'(Fiscal|yeah)))` in your case

To find by exact match, you can pass `text` as a list: `soup.find_all(class_="label",text=['Fiscal', 'yeah'])`

"Find Fiscal and NOT yeah" logics can be covered by using this: `soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'lfloat'}, text=re.compile(r'(Fiscal|[^yeah])'))` (not sure here)

Comment: This only matches the *whole text*, not partially.

Comment: That only answers part of the question though, but yes, a regular expression that matches the specific combinations the OP is looking for (or excludes specific combinations) is the answer.

Comment: However, a regular expression that ensures that *two* words are *both* present is not so trivial.

Comment: you could replace `{'class':'lfloat'}` with simple `'lfloat'` here.

Comment: the list finds whether *any* of 'Fiscal' and 'year' words are in the text - OP asks for *both*. The "not year" regex is incorrect.