# Beautifulsoup find_all() with multiple AND conditions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a a HTML source with multiple `<sup></sup>` tags of which some also contain `<a></a>` tags. My goal is to delete all superscripts which also contain a link while wrapping the superscripts without a link in square brackets. My code works to a certain extent: it decomposes the correct `<a>` tags but also wraps the now empty `<sup>` tags in brackets. I tried to find a way to use find_all() with multiple AND conditions for the `<sup>` and `<a>` tag but to no avail. P.m.: SO has a thread regarding [multiple OR conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908349/use-multiple-conditions-in-beautifulsoup).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<h1>
        <b> Heading </b>
      <sup>
        <a href="LINK_1">1</a>
      </sup>
    </h1>
    <p>
      <sup>2</sup>
      This is a paragraph
      <sup><a href="LINK_2">3</a></sup>
    </p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# remove superscripts with links
for superscript in soup.find_all("sup"):
    for suplink in superscript.find_all("a"):
        suplink.decompose()

# wrap remaining superscripts in brackets
    superscript.insert(0, "[")
    superscript.insert(len(superscript.contents), "]")

print(html)
```

Result:

```
    <h1>
    <b> Heading </b>
    <sup>[
    
    ]</sup>
    </h1>
    <p>
    <sup>[2]</sup>
        This is a paragraph
        <sup>[]</sup>
    </p>
```

What it should look like:

```
    <h1>
    <b> Heading </b>
    </h1>
    <p>
    <sup>[2]</sup>
          This is a paragraph
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively traverse the source and update the `sup`s accordingly:

```
import bs4
def update_sup(d):
   if d.name == 'sup':
      if any(not isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString) for i in d.contents):
         d.extract()
      else:
         d.string = f'[{d.get_text(strip=True)}]'
   for i in filter(lambda x:not isinstance(x, bs4.element.NavigableString), d.contents):
       update_sup(i)

html = '''<h1>
    <b> Heading </b>
  <sup>
    <a href="LINK_1">1</a>
  </sup>
</h1>
<p>
  <sup>2</sup>
  This is a paragraph
  <sup><a href="LINK_2">3</a></sup>
</p>'''
d = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
update_sup(d)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
<h1>
<b> Heading </b>

</h1>
<p>
<sup>[2]</sup>
  This is a paragraph
  
</p>
```

Comment: This has solved the issue as stated in the OP; thank you so much for taking the time to answer. Applied to the real source it became apparent that there are a few instances where the superscripts are wrapped in double `<sup>` tags such as this: `<sup><sup><a href="LINK">NUMBER</a></sup></sup>`. In these instances one `sup` tag remains.

Comment: @quadratecode Please see my recent edit. I updated the solution to remove any `sup`s that contain non-text elements as child nodes.